# Will Apache mod_rewrite also rewrite links inside transfered HTML?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to force mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs in the HTML it gets back from (rewritten) request URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `mod_rewrite` does now know anything about the content; it operates purely on URIs, Headers and Environment-Variables. If you are using mod_rewrite to proxy content, you might find that [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: The current documentation for this module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html .

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [modproxyperlhtml](http://modproxyhtml.darold.net/install.html) which has better performance and more features than mod_proxy_html